# Mac Permissions Nightmare - XAMPP

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, apache-http-server, xampp

I am making a conscience effort to use the terminal more on Mac and when I thought I understood permissions and accessing specific files and services I am more lost than ever.

I recently installed XAMPP on my Mac but after fight with Virtual Host and eventually getting that to work now my servers will not start at all.

**I have a few questions:**

**1.** If I install `XAMPP` using the installer are all the files now owned by root?

**2.** If I go in as my_username and edit files do I now own that file?

**3.** If I or root own the files can daemon not run them?

**4.** I see the "first aid" fix permissions in the utility is that my only option to start from the beginning before I started `chmod` and `chown` to get the Vhost to work.

I am not seeing any logs for startup anywhere in XAMPP so I am not sure why they are not starting. If some one can help me wrap my head around permission specificly when running software that is installed.

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide to help make this any easier to troubleshoot.